# How to change random uploaded filename in S3 - Sails.JS

Tags: amazon-s3, sails.js, skipper

currently I'm using SailsJS to create my own web-apps. And I'm using skipper-s3 to upload files to AWS S3. And this is my code:

```
req.file('uploadFile').upload({
  adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
  key: 'KEY',
  secret: 'SECRET',
  bucket: 'BUCKET',
  ACL: 'public-read'
}, function whenDone(err, filesUploaded) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.negotiate(err);
  }

  var pt = {
    user: req.session.User.id,
    agency: req.param('id'),
    path: filesUploaded[0].extra.Location,
    filename: filesUploaded[0].filename
  };

  Transaction.create(pt, function TransactionCreated(err, trans){
    if(err) return next(err);

    return res.ok({
      files: filesUploaded,
      textParams: req.params.all(),
      trans: trans
    });
  })
});
```

So I already put the 'path' and 'original filename' to MongoDB. But the 'filename' inside S3 is already changed with 'random name'. So, is it possible to change to 'original filename' while uploading? OR automatically change to 'original filename' when user want to download it?

Regards,
John Elmer Semaya

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking [skipper documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skipper#customizing-at-rest-filenames-for-uploads) I have found about `saveAs` options. Only have to put it inside `req.file('name').upload` to let it saved with your original name or with another custom name.

this is the example:

```
var newFilename = req.file('uploadFile')._files[0].stream.filename;

req.file('uploadFile').upload({
   adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
   key: 'KEY',
   secret: 'SECRET',
   bucket: 'BUCKET',
   ACL: 'public-read,
   saveAs: newFilename //this is how you put custom name when upload file
},
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the key parameter of s3params.

```
const options = {
  adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
  key: 'KEY',
  secret: 'SECRET',
  bucket: 'BUCKET',
  s3params: {Key: 'full/path/to/file.jpg'} //no leading slash prevents empty folder
}

const adapter = require('skipper-better-s3')(options),
      receiver = adapter.receive();

req.file('uploadFile').upload(receiver, function(err,filesUploaded){
  //do something...
})

//More useful below

const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/my-file.jpg');

receiver.write(file, () => { 
  console.log(file.extra);
});
```